# Conditionally making readonly to WPF DataGridCell

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a situation that needs to conditionally make readonly to wpf datagrid cell. There is IsReadOnly property in DataGridCell. But unfortunately, that property is readonly! Is there any way to do it?
ant.

Comment: the IsReadOnly is a boolean result to check that wheather the cell is readOnly or Not, that's why it is a readonly property :)

Comment: IsReadOnly property is read/write on DataGrid which is the root element of datagrid. IsReadOnly property is not settable in sub-elements of DataGrid such as DataGridCell because it doesn’t make sense to set DataGridCell.IsReadOnly to true when DataGrid.IsReadyOnly is false

Comment: @VoodooChild The main reason you can't set IsReadOnly on a DataGridCell is because they are transient. They are created and thrown away as needed because the DataGrid doesn't keep all of its rows and cells in memory at any point in time. So there is no place for you to even set this property, even if it was writable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030143/wpf-datagrid-with-some-read-only-rows

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to use the [DataGrid.BeginningEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.beginningedit.aspx) event to conditionally check if the cell is editable and then set the Cancel property on the event args if not.

Comment: The most effective way how to prevent editing for some cells. It's even prevent the editing focus on cell after row above was edited.

Answer (score 7):

The similar solution as Goblin above, but with a little code samples:

The idea is to dynamically switch the `CellEditingTemplate` between two templates, one is the same as the one in the `CellTemplate`, the other is for editing. This makes the edit mode acts exactly the same as the non-editing cell although it is in edit mode.

The following is some sample code for doing this, notice that this approach requires `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

First, define two templates for read-only and editing cells:

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <!-- the non-editing cell -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ReadonlyCellTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyCellValue}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- the editing cell -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableCellTemplate">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding MyCellValue}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Then define a data template with additional `ContentPresenter` layer and use `Trigger` to switch the `ContentTemplate` of the `ContentPresenter`, so the above two templates can be switched dynamically by the `IsEditable` binding:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource ReadonlyCellTemplate}">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <!-- the additional layer of content presenter -->
      <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ReadonlyCellTemplate}" />
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <!-- dynamically switch the content template by IsEditable binding -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable}" Value="True">
          <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditableCellTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Another very simple solution to this problem is to use a Style of the DataGridCell

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="disabledCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource disabledCellStyle}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource disabledCellStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn/> /*always enabled*/
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This style assumes that there is a IsEnabled property in the ViewModel.

This does not make the cell read only but disabled. It is almost the same thing except that is cannot be selected. This solution might not be applicable in all cases due to this.

Comment: Another side-effect of disabling the cell is that when you press up/down and you bump on the disabled cell, the cursor movement stops there. If you have a grid that should be traversable with the keyboard this has a very buggy feeling.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the TemplateSelector property to set two different DataTemplates (one writable and one readonly) based on your logic? Just create a class that inherits from DataTemplateSelector and override the SelectTemplate() method (here you have access to the datacontext).