# How to make WPF datagrid cell ReadOnly for certain rows?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I use a WPF data grid to edit a database table. The table contains several records with 16 columns (properties).

I want to make a column read only if the user tries to edit it when one of the columns of the selected record has a specific value (in other words, disable editing of that particular column for certain records).

I was thinking to bind to column **IsReadOnly** property, but I do not know how to pass the column which I need to verify (or at least the current row) as a converter parameter.

**Does anybody have an idea how to do this?**

Comment: You can pass entire UI elements into IValueConverters.  Not convinced its a great idea, however.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350388/can-i-pass-entire-ui-element-into-a-ivalueconverter  You could pass your entire DataGrid into the IValueConverter  and look at the selected row.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution here. Using the DataGrid.BeginningEdit event to conditionally check if the cell is editable and then set the Cancel property on the event args if not.

[Conditionally making readonly to WPF DataGridCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947125/conditionally-making-readonly-to-wpf-datagridcell)

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making the specific `DataColumn` Readonly, while setting the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`. Consider the following as an example:

```
        DataTable tab = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col = tab.Columns.Add("a");
        // data added code
        foreach (DataColumn col in tab.Columns)
        foreach (DataRow r in tab.Rows)
        {
                if (r[col].Equals("..."))
                {
                    col.ReadOnly = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
```