# Disable row selecting in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I want to disable DataRow selection in WPF DataGrid.

First I have tried `IsHitTestVisible` property, it disables whole row. If I want to put an `HyperLink` it will be disabled.

I have tried to get rid of it by overriding `DataGridRow` `ControlTemplate`'s :

(Whole template code is huge but i just put the important section)

```
 <VisualState x:Name="Normal_Selected">
     <Storyboard>
         <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
             <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlMediumColor}" />
         </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
             <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlDarkColor}" />
         </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         <!--<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
             <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
         </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
     </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
```

Actually selecting a row in DataGrid will change `Forground` color. I have tried `Triggers` but it won't work. In the code above, I have tried to keep foreground `Black` but it throws in a run-time error.

How can i disable Row selection in a DataGrid ?

Comment: If i am getting this right, you have a DG with rows containing hyper links, you want to disable row's selection but leave the links clickable ?

Comment: Yea. In a DataGridRow we can put a lots of controls. i want to hide selection highlight actually (because it seems that i cant get rid of Selection)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882423/datagrid-disabling-rows-wpf

Comment: Making rows read-only doesn't prevent to row selecting. the only way (the only way that i have found) was to make `IsHitTestVisible` to `false`. in this way all clickable control on the target control will turns to non-clickable one. but it will not solve my problem. I want to disable back-color changes in row selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work very well if you are using wpf. However, it doesn't work if you are doing winui3

```
   <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
```