# How to make the perticular row in data grid as non editable field in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to make the particular row at data grid as a non editable filed using WPF.so please help me out

Comment: what is the condition for that particular row

Answer (score 1):

You can make the cell non-editable by setting the property `IsReadOnly` for that column as true. Also, you can disable the entire datagrid to be non-editable by setting this property to true. But this property is not there for DatagridRow, you have to create your own `Depenedency property` and bind to that property through `style of DataGridRow`. You can refer to this sample for disabling particular row in datagrid - [Disable row in dataGrid](http://blog.spencen.com/2009/04/25/readonly-rows-and-cells-in-a-datagrid.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921131/wpf-datagrid-disable-editing-in-certain-rows) is a way how to disable it via triggers and value converter. Probably it will help you